# How can i insert data from a table row into Database on clicking a button in the row in C# MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that populates data into a table and displays it. Each table row has a button which should save the data into a database. I know how to save the data from a controller, I just want to know how can I pass the data from the clicked table row to a controller?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Properties)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrossYield)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.listPrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.monthlyRent)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.yearBuilt)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.address1)
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.address2),
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.district),
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.state),
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.zip),
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.country).
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="clsActionButton" id="idAddButton" onclick="idAddButton_onclick();">Add</button>
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

This is my table that populates the data from a model. When i click the add button, I want to send the entire row data to a controller.

Comment: In order to do that, you basically have 2 choices: 1) have a form element on each row so that the button will serve as submit button 2) write JavaScripts to manually get the data and post back to the server. Both methods don't work well IMO: 1) a form is not allowed to be a direct child of <tr /> 2) You have to write many hard-coded JavaScript codes to get data for each cell. When things change, the whole thing becomes harder and harder to maintain. I would suggest you a different approach: leave table view as the summary view. On each row, you can have a href to open up a modal for each row.

Comment: The modal/popup (or could even be a separate page) will have a view model that represents just a single row of records (probably with an identifier).

Comment: @DavidLiang At this moment, I believe I would like to go with the JS code because of the time constraint. I can't find anything online on how to send the data using JS and I don't have much knowledge about it. Could you help me with the piece of code i need to write ?

Comment: Ok. What data do you need to send back? All of them?

Comment: @DavidLiang - yes the entire row data for whichever row button is clicked. I want that to reach my controller, where i have written the code to pass it to database. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When this page is rendered it will have multiple buttons with the same id.  You should be aware that that is not valid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Liang makes some good points.  Maybe this approach could work for you.  The basic idea is to convert the data of each row into JSON.  Then send the JSON to the server.  Because we use a service, i.e. NewtonSoft.Json, to serialize and deserialize the data we avoid the hardcoded values problem that David Liang mentions.

I've written a demo to show the approach.  I've tried to keep it the same as yours but have had to make guesses as you didn't include everything.

First you will need to install the nuget package Newtonsoft.Json.

Here is the server side code, i.e. the viewModels and the controller.  The GET just sends test data to the view.  The POST method is the one you will be interested in, it accepts a JSON string and deserializes it to give you your row object.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace InsertRow.Controllers
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<BuildingViewModel> Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class BuildingViewModel
    {
        public string GrossYield { get; set; }
        public string listPrice { get; set; }
        public string monthlyRent { get; set; }
        public string yearBuilt { get; set; }
        public AddressViewModel Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string district { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {       
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myTestData = new List<BuildingViewModel>()
            {
                new BuildingViewModel
                {
                    GrossYield = "gy1",
                    listPrice = "lp1",
                    monthlyRent = "mr1",
                    yearBuilt = "yb1",
                    Addresses = new AddressViewModel
                    {
                        address1 = "a11",
                        address2 = "a21",
                        district = "d1",
                        state = "s1",
                        zip = "z1",
                        country = "c1"
                    }
                },
                new BuildingViewModel
                {
                    GrossYield = "gy2",
                    listPrice = "lp2",
                    monthlyRent = "mr2",
                    yearBuilt = "yb2",
                    Addresses = new AddressViewModel
                    {
                        address1 = "a12",
                        address2 = "a22",
                        district = "d2",
                        state = "s2",
                        zip = "z2",
                        country = "c2"
                    }
                }
            };

            var viewModel = new MyViewModel
            {
                Properties = myTestData
            };           

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(string rowJson)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildingViewModel>(rowJson);
            //code to save the data to the database goes here.
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the index.cshtml file

```
@using InsertRow.Controllers
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model MyViewModel

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Properties)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrossYield)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.listPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.monthlyRent)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.yearBuilt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.address1)
                    <br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.address2),
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.district),
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.state),
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.zip),
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Addresses.country).
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button data-row="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)"
                            class="clsActionButton">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".clsActionButton");
    var addButtonCount = addButtons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < addButtonCount; i++) {
        addButtons[i].addEventListener('click', onAddRowClicked);
    }

    function onAddRowClicked(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn = this;
        var data = btn.dataset.row;
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.method = "post";
        form.action = '/home/index';
        var antiForgeryInput = document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
        form.appendChild(antiForgeryInput); 
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("value", data);
        input.setAttribute("name", "rowJson");
        form.appendChild(input); 
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Note what I have done to the button.  I have added all the data for the row as a data attribute.  The benefit of this approach is that should the data change in the future the code for this button can stay the same.

Note also the javascript.  When the button is clicked we create a form on the fly, add the antiforgery token and the data from the button that was clicked and then submit to the server. Once the server has deserialized you will have your row data as requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave, this is what I was looking for. Yeah, I realized that later that all my buttons would have the same id and so I removed it but forgot to edit it here.